# Android The type dialog listener is not visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, fragment, listener

I am using a Dialog Fragment from within another fragment. When both fragments are in the same folder everything is fine. There is a folder for dialogs. Once I move the Dialog Fragment to this folder the calling fragment produces this error in Eclipse under problems i.e. not at run-time.

```
The type DialogFragment.Listener is not visible.
```

The set up in the calling fragment is in com.example.test and it looks like this:

```
import com.example.test.dialogs.DialogFragment;
...
public class TaskFragment extends Fragment implements
        DialogFragment.Listener {
```

If I move the DialogFragment file up one level then I don't have the issue. What do I have to change in the set up so that the listener in the subfolder becomes visible?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have important problems if u do 
In eclipse press shift + ctrl + o it's gonna fix importants automatically

Comment: I tried it but it did not change anything. Usually import issues are displayed under 'problems' but there is nothing.